# concatenate left and upper cells with a color

Tags: vba

I am looking for macro in VBA that goes through a range and concatenate all the left values (until column A) + upper values (until row 1) using a given color of each cell in the range.
Do you think it's possible?
thank you

Comment: What have you tried so far? What kind of values are you working with? Do you have a sample of the expected output? You need to provide a lot more information if you want a solution!

Comment: Hello, this is how it looks today. the objective is to make it more dynamic with VBA as number of columns and rows can change and the manual maintenance of the file is too heavy.Unfortunately I am not a VBA expert and I couldn't achieve much. Any help please? http://hpics.li/b923e35

Comment: Why not use `SumProduct` function from Excel and have something closer to a proper data base in your sheet 1 (which will be far more efficient to read, sort, ...)?

Comment: Actually the files i am using are large, as well as the number of rows in the file. It would really help if I can have this concatenation work.

Comment: @Aslaam Even though I submitted an answer could you elaborate on what you mean by "using a given color"?

Answer (score 0):

I have tested this one and it works based on your example. Give it a go :)

```
Function concatenateLeftAndTop() As String
Dim firstColumnToTheLeft As Long
Dim firstRowToTheTop As Long
Dim functionColumn As Long
Dim functionRow As Long
Dim output As String
Dim i As Long

'Set your workbook - in this version I select the active workbook
Set myBook = ActiveWorkbook

'Set up your worksheet - In this version I select the active worksheet
Set mySheet = myBook.ActiveSheet

' Finding which column and which row the function is in
functionColumn = Application.Caller.Column
functionRow = Application.Caller.Row

'Concatenating
With mySheet
    ' Finding the first column to the left
    firstColumnToTheLeft = .Cells(functionRow, functionColumn).End(xlToLeft).Column
    firstRowToTheTop = .Cells(functionRow, functionColumn).End(xlUp).Row

    'Initial Value
    output = .Cells(functionRow, firstColumnToTheLeft)
    'Cells to the left
    For i = (firstColumnToTheLeft + 1) To (functionColumn - 1)
        output = output & ";" & .Cells(functionRow, i)
    Next i
    'Cells Above
    For i = firstRowToTheTop To (functionRow - 1)
        output = output & ";" & .Cells(i, functionColumn)
    Next i
End With

'Output
concatenateLeftAndTop = output

End Function
```